# Trigger or computed column?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I had a table `employeeswipe_tbl` in SQL Server 2008 with these columns:

```
create employeeswipe_tbl swipepk int (
swipepk int primary ,
empid  int,
dateofswipe date ,
intime datetime,
outime datetime,
logduration  time
)
```

When employee login in the `intime, empid, dateofswipe` is entered and when log out the `outime` is updated against `swipepk`

Now what I want is when I update `outtime` the `logduration` will be automatically calculated like

```
logduration  = outtime - intime
```

I am thinking of a some ideas like a computed column or a trigger. Can anyone give a good option considering I am a beginner ?

Comment: The difference between two dates & times is a time span, not a date & time.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Iam editing and making the duration to time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A computed column is usually a better option than a trigger. Triggers can be disabled. A computed column is "always" correct:

```
create table employeeswipe_tbl (
swipepk int primary key,
empid  int,
intime datetime,
outime datetime,
dateofswipe AS CONVERT(date,intime) ,
logduration AS DATEDIFF(second,intime,outime)
)
```

As indicated in my comment, the difference between two `datetime`s would be a time span, not another `datetime`. There's no time span type in SQL Server, so just keeping the difference in seconds is probably best - do any formatting of it into hours, minutes and seconds during display. This will make it easier if you need to, for instance, add together several rows worth of data.

---

<strike>Side note - I was considering making `dateofswipe` a computed column also - isn't it just the date part of `intime`?</strike>

Comment: the dateofswipe  is a datepart of intime

Comment: ALTER TABLE EmployeSwipeDaily_tbl ADD Duration1 AS DATEDIFF(second,EmployeSwipeDaily_tbl.intime,EmployeSwipeDaily_tbl.outime)

Comment: @sreenathsreenath - you shouldn't include the table name. A computed column can only reference other columns from the same table.